# How to clear the error "... is not a valid value for property ..."

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2022, dependency-properties

I'm creating a WPF application and I've created a `UserControl` for buttons that navigate from one page to another.

My program runs fine but I have errors being shown in VS that should prevent my program from compiling but doesn't.

```
Severity    Code    Description File    Line    Suppression State
Error XDG0010 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.XSurface.Wpf.Page' is not a valid value for property 'Page'.  
C:\Users\...\Desktop Front End\Views\Windows\Main.xaml  29
```

In my Main.xaml file I have the following code.

```
...
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Desktop_Front_End.Views.Windows"
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Desktop_Front_End.Resources.UserControls"
xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Desktop_Front_End.Views.Pages"
...
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,2,0,2">
    <controls:btnNav PathData="{StaticResource VecBuilding}" 
                     Description="UI Demo"
                     Nav_Click="_Nav_Click">
            
         <controls:btnNav.Page >
             <pages:UiTheme />
         </controls:btnNav.Page>
     </controls:btnNav>
     <controls:btnNav PathData="{StaticResource VecBuilding}" 
...
```

In my `UserControl` I have the following:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Page", typeof(Page), typeof(btnNav), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public dynamic Page
    {
        get { return GetValue(PageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PageProperty, value); }
    }
```

I've tried adjusting `public dynamic Page` to `public Page Page` but when I do this my program does not compile.

How do I get rid of these error in Visual Studio?

Comment: When there is `typeof(Page)` as argument to the Register method, the property type must obviously be `Page`. What exactly does it mean when you write "*does not compile*"?

Comment: Hi,@Mandelbrotter. Could you share with me project structure and all code without private information that reproduces the issue for analysis?

Comment: Please check the Page types of the property and the value. The error message says the value's type doesn't match the property type. I assume you accidently imported the wrong reference. Error message says value type is `Microsoft.VisualStudio.XSurface.Wpf.Page`. You very likely are using `System.Windows.Controls.Page`. Fixing the namespace of the using reference might solve the problem.

Comment: In general you should avoid `dynamic` as it eliminates the compiler support (type checking). This is an important feature that helps to write robust code. Always use strong typing when possible. It doesn't appear to be reasonable to use `dynamic` here. It even does harm as it masks type errors. That's why your code doesn't compile without `dynamic`.

Comment: `dynamic` is meant to be used in very specific and extremely rare cases .

Comment: Can you clarify which Page class you are using? `public System.Windows.Controls.Page Page` or `public Microsoft.VisualStudio.XSurface.Wpf.Page Page`?

Comment: @MustafaÖzçetin I'm using public System.Windows.Controls.Page Page

Comment: @Mandelbrotter: Change `dynamic` to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.XSurface.Wpf.Page` or whatever type your `UiTheme` class is.